# Why does 'this.value' work but e.value doesn't?

Tags: javascript, this

I'm new.  I've read a lot on stackoverflow, but this is my first question.  Hopefully it's not a silly one.  I know the crowd can be harsh at times, and often deservingly so.  :)

In the following code, when you enter text in the first input box, the alert does not show what you input.  However in the 2nd box, when you key something in, the alert shows it.

The difference is in the use of 'this.value' vs 'e.value'.

I'm thinking that they should both work since 'e.value' references an element and I thought 'this.value' does also, but obviously am missing something since it does not do the same thing.

Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><script>
window.onload = function () {var e;
    e = document.getElementById('eInput');
    if (!e.onkeyup) {e.onkeyup = function () {alert (e.value); }; }
    e = document.getElementById('thisInput');
    if (!e.onkeyup) {e.onkeyup = function () {alert (this.value); }; }
}
</script></head>
<body>
<input type="text" id='eInput'></input><br><br>
<input type="text" id='thisInput'></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `e` in the function should refer to the element that triggered the event. You should alter it to `function (e) {alert (e.target.value); }; }`

Now the `e` is the event that triggerd the onkeyup function and you can access the target to get the value.

see http://jsfiddle.net/yAaYX/

Comment: Thank you. New technique for me.  I'll have to study this some more.  It does work per your example.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the first input doesn't work - your `e` variable is getting overwritten and it points to the 2nd input, which is empty at that time.

If you remove the 2 lines of the 2nd input you'll see it works just fine with `e.value`-
[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/WBssG/)

Or just give the variables different names - `e1` and `e2` - [example](http://jsfiddle.net/WBssG/1/)

Comment: Thank you.  e = element.  I did not realize that the e being changed after I assign the event function to the eInput element would matter.  Since it's reassigned after I assign the event to the 1st element.  Then I'm just reusing the variable to assign an event to the 2nd element.  I'll have to read about this more since I don't understand why reuse of the e variable is a problem here.